# go get private repositories in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, go

I'm having an issue retrieving my go repository in Azure Devops I followed this instructions on this blog post https://seb-nyberg.medium.com/using-go-modules-with-private-azure-devops-repositories-4664b621f782 I'm using the HTTP but I still ran into some problem.

Steps:

So at first I've created a PAT in Azure DEVOPS

Then execute this in Powershell 7

```
git config --global url."https://doctor-go:${PAT-TOKEN}@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://dev.azure.com"
```

Next get the repository

```
go get -v dev.azure.com/GoJack/Doctor-Go/_git/doctor-go-client-service.git
```

Also my GOPRIVATE path

```
set GOPRIVATE=dev.azure.com
```

Error message

```
   # cd .; git ls-remote https://dev.azure.com/GoJack/Doctor-Go/_git/doctor-go-client-service
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/GoJack/Doctor-Go/_git/doctor-go-client-service/'
# cd .; git ls-remote git+ssh://dev.azure.com/GoJack/Doctor-Go/_git/doctor-go-client-service
ssh: connect to host dev.azure.com port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
# cd .; git ls-remote ssh://dev.azure.com/GoJack/Doctor-Go/_git/doctor-go-client-service
ssh: connect to host dev.azure.com port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
go get: module dev.azure.com/GoJack/Doctor-Go/_git/doctor-go-client-service.git: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\repo\Go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\ce0ff448242f9d12cad770f534c0eb079d44a6ee26be6ade1eee5255bf833d58: exit status 128:
        fatal: unable to connect to dev.azure.com:
        dev.azure.com[0: 13.107.42.20]: errno=Unknown error
```

Comment: Maybe you can try setting `.gitconfig` with the full path as the original Microsoft Docs suggest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/go-get?view=azure-devops#https

Comment: It doesn't work and I still get the same error.

Comment: I moved it to github for now but if anyone has a good solution please post your answer

Comment: I get the same issue. Can you perhaps share the link to the GitHub issue? Many thanks.

Comment: did anyone ever figure this out? this started happening to us one random day at work